# TransactionWriteItems with update overrides existing entry in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, transactions, amazon-dynamodb

According to [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html#transaction-apis-txwriteitems), if an item exists in the table, TransactWriteItems will update its attributes, instead of overriding it like a put operation. However, in practice I think it does the override instead of update.

Here is my code snippet in Java:

```
private TransactionWriteRequest buildTransactionWriteRequest(List<UserEntity> userEntities) {
        TransactionWriteRequest transactionWriteRequest = new TransactionWriteRequest();

        userEntities.forEach(userEntity -> {
            // Entity exists in the table, update it
            if (userEntity.getVersion() != null) {
                transactionWriteRequest.addUpdate(userEntity);
            } else { // Entity does not exist in the table, create it
                transactionWriteRequest.addPut(userEntity);
            }
        });

        return transactionWriteRequest;
    }
```

An UserEntity is fetched by querying the table with its hash and range key, so if it exists, it will include the version attribute in the returned entity. Then dynamoDBMapper calls transaction write to write items

```
dynamoDBMapper.transactionWrite(transactionWriteRequest);
```

When testing, when I provide an existing item and try to update part of its attributes, after the call, it seems the attributes which are not part of the update got replaced by null values. However, the version attribute seems to have correctly incremented by 1.

Does anyone know why transaction update works like a transaction put, or something is wrong with my code logics? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
userEntities.forEach(userEntity -> {
            // Entity exists in the table, update it
            if (userEntity.getVersion() != null) {
                transactionWriteRequest.addUpdate(userEntity);
            } else { // Entity does not exist in the table, create it
                transactionWriteRequest.addPut(userEntity);
            }
        });
```

Dont do this, if the item doesn't exist an UpdateItem will add it.

Furthermore, transactions with DynamoDB Mapper do not provide the ability to change the save behavior. It uses `Update` by default and gives the following behavior:

> **UPDATE**—during a save operation, all modeled attributes are updated, and unmodeled attributes are unaffected. Primitive number types (byte, int, long) are set to 0. Object types are set to null.

I would suggest using the low level client to model your transactions to have control over what values are changed.

Comment: "if the item doesn't exist an UpdateItem will add it", this will be handled by the addPut line, won't it?

Could you elaborate on the part about low level client, don't fully understand?

Comment: It's handed by the SDK, you dont need the condition or the `addPut` line. The mapper client which you use does not give you configuration over the save behaviour for transactions. Therefore you need to use the standard client: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.SDKs.Interfaces.html

Comment: Thanks for your help Lee. The default save behavior for DynamoDBMapper is UPDATE, which only updates modeled attributes and leave un-modeled attributes intact.

Does that suggest I can just remove ```addPut``` line and have everything added in the ```addUpdate```? The default save behavior suggests the mapper should create a new item if the item to update does not exist. Correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: Thats correct, but you will still have the issue with values being set to Null, unless you set them before you make the transaction. My suggestion is to read the item into memory, update the values you want to change then submit the transaction.